# For a balanced binary search tree what is the worst case case time complexity for accessing all elements within a range of nodes?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation, balanced-search-trees, binary-search-trees

I have this question which is asking for the worst case time complexity for a balanced binary search tree, assume the nodes are labeled as integers and we consider a range of `[nodex, nodey]`, `nodex<=nodey`. And also given that the range has exactly  **k** nodes, **k** can be at most **n** ie. total number of nodes. The question asks what is the worst case time complexity of accessing all the
**k** nodes in given range. According to my knowledge of Time-Complexiy analysis It must be `O(k*log(n))` since there are **k** elements and each element takes `O(log(n))` time in worst case ( since the tree is balanced ) this seems very plausible, However the answer seems to be `O(k + log(n))`, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to construct the tree containing those values:

1. Explore the BST until you find the root of a subtree that is between the bounds;
2. Explore the left part of the subtree, and trim branches on the left that have a root $\leqslant node_x$;
3. Do the same thing on the right for roots $\geqslant node_y$

Each of those steps are done in $O(\log n)$ since the BST is balanced. Once you have constructed the tree, just do a tree traversal (in-order for example) of it. This last step is indeed done in $O(k)$.

Comment: I see, Now I get it, I was confusing the range of nodes to be visited, to each one of the nodes, but I see why that's redundant all we would need is the end points of the range and since an inorder traversal can be done in ```O(k)``` the two have to be added, of course. It was so silly of me. Thanks for the answer.